# What are the special effects for each damage type, and when do they trigger?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that when I use a weapon with cold damage, every attack "snares" my targets, even when I don't use any skill or item which explicitly snares or slows. I'm guessing this is due to the cold damage.

- Do other damage types have a special effect this way? If they do, what are those effects?
- Does it also happen if I get a bonus damage from a source which is not directly on the weapon? e.g. if I have a ring which adds cold damage, will all my attacks snare?
- Do these special effects always trigger on attack, or only under certain conditions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unlike in Diablo II, **on-hit elemental damage is simply that - bonus damage**, with the *sole* exception of cold damage (which has a small snare). Frost damage does a little less damage comparatively because of this.

While there was originally a more complex critical hit system (as documented below), **that functionality did not make it to the final game**.

Critical hits just add damage.

---

### Historical Answer:

More interestingly, in  the Diablo III Beta, each type of damage has a different effect on a critical.

- **Physical**: Double Damage
- **Arcane**: Silences targets for 4 seconds (prevents abilities)
- **Cold**: Freezes targets for 2 seconds (Duration can be affected by talents, etc.)
- **Fire**: Sets them on fire, fire DoT (tick rate scales off weapon speed)
- **Lightning**: Stuns targets for 2 seconds (Duration can be affected by talents, etc.)

Poison and Holy presumably have effects on a critical hit also, but I haven't been able to find info on them.

Comment: Critical hits that result in a killing blow with elemental damage also result in *awesome* animations.

Comment: All of which involve invalidating the corpse. Can't resurrect a fallen grunt when he's melted into a puddle of acid, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a 10-20 dmg +5 cold dmg, your weapon will not do 15-25! It deals 5-10 physical +5 cold. The extra is already added to the weapon tooltip white text. This is easily verified by adding a gem to a socket (a +5 gem for example), the tooltip will update to 15-20 dmg (white text).
2. If you use an ability with specific dmg (witch doctor poison dart deals 100% weapon dmg as poison) then I'm not sure. I think it does poison dmg based on your weapon total damage, don't know if the cold dmg or its effect still occurs.

> Does it also happen if I get a bonus damage from a source which is not directly on the weapon? e.g. if I have a ring which adds cold damage, will all my attacks snare?

There is no specific dmg on other items except on weapons, rings only add +x all dmg.